# python django 1.7.6 start a new project with a template: zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, django

I have installed django-1.7.6 under a new virtualenv and python's version is 2.7.6.

When I start a new project with a template: edge2, I have encountered a error: zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file.

With a command:

`django-admin.py startproject --template=https://github.com/arocks/edge/archive/master.zip --extension=py,md,html,env example`

Following is all the verbose of console's output:

`django-admin.py startproject --template=https://github.com/arocks/edge/archive/master.zip --extension=py,md,html,env example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py", line 31, in handle
    super(Command, self).handle('project', project_name, target, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 122, in handle
    base_subdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 205, in handle_template
    return self.extract(absolute_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 299, in extract
    archive.extract(filename, tempdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/archive.py", line 49, in extract
    with Archive(path) as archive:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/archive.py", line 58, in __init__
    self._archive = self._archive_cls(file)(file)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/archive.py", line 181, in __init__
    self._archive = zipfile.ZipFile(file)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 766, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 807, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file`

Actually, I have encountered errors like above when I start a new django project with a template.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your command and it works for me.

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 807
```

Throws an [IOError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IOError). This can have multiple reasons like not enough disk space.